# Vue project 404 using vue +vite

Tags: vuejs3, vite

Today I published a websites using two method, one is successfully, but the other one failed with 404
Success one: I can visit this website with http://10.110.110.110:8005

[image]

But the other method failed, with this method, I need to add a subpath 'eleave' in to visit url like http://10.110.110.110/eleave/

[image]

Here is browser debug img, you can see subpath 'eleave' missed
[image]

I tried publicPath and base, but didn't work, and it seems nothing relative to publicPath and base compile into output files
Here is my vite.config.js screenshot
[image]

Here is my index.html screenshot
[image]

Here is my dev environment
visual studio code:
[image]

Vue version:
[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6225326)